Why does this LED turn on?
Context: I have designed a custom data acquisition board around the MAX11046 ADC. While troubleshooting my previous problem I discovered some unexpected behaviour.
Here is the schematic of the ADC section:

Problem: When I set my multimeter to check for continuity and test various configurations, the D102 LED illuminates:



Of course, testing LEDs and/or continuity is nothing new to me; I am well aware that the test is done via the multimeter sending out a small current. My question is more so how is current flowing through the LED --I can't seem to wrap my head around how this is possible? Is there some potential current path I am not considering? Is the ADC damaged?
If needed, the full schematics and PCB can be found here.

There's probably ESD protection diodes to GND and VCC on those lines inside the chip.

@Unimportant Thank you, that makes sense. However, when I pull those pins high it literally powers the entire board from those pins --both LEDs in this case, with a reading of ~1.1V. Would this still be a result of current flowing through the ESD diodes? It interferes with the functioning of the circuit; I am using a 3.3V logic level. Certainly the ESD breakdown voltage is not that low, and this has not been designed this way?

They are normal diodes that conduct with a Vf of +-0.7V. So yes, if you apply a voltage to any of those pins while VCC is not present the diodes will conduct and current will flow onto the supply rail. That's why practically all datasheets say most pins may not go outside supply rail voltages.

As @Unimportant says, as the IO pin goes above VCC it will bleed current into VCC which in turn will light the LED, this is quite typical

I appreciate the help immensely, a great thanks to both of you. Either of you should turn this into an answer so that I can accept it.
